# Form only submits after 2 clicks instead of one - react, express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a form that submits only when button is clicked twice. How can I change to one click? I have not included input validation below as it takes many lines but its basically simple if / else statements like if no input set error. The form was submitting before on one click, however since I changed something (don't rembeber what exactly) form does not submit on one click. Code below:

```
  handleFormSubmission = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const credentials = {
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
  email: this.state.signupEmail,
};


if (
  !this.state.errorPasswordStatus &&
  !this.state.errorUsernameStatus &&
  !this.state.errorPasswordConfirmStatus &&
  !this.state.errorSignupEmailStatus
) {
  this.setState({
    buttonDisabled: true,
  });
  signup(credentials).then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: false,
    });
    if (!res.status) {
      if (res.errorMessage === "*Username already taken.") {
        this.setState({
          errorUsername: "*Username already taken.",
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          error: res.errorMessage,
        });
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.accessToken);
      this.props.authenticate(res.data.user);
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This random snippet is not super helpful. You should try to focus your question to more than "Why doesn't this random bit of code work." I suspect you are not even showing us the problem area.

Comment: @Deadron so helpful :)